# High IO latency in games when loading sounds

Tags: hard-drive, audio, games

I recognized the behaviour of games hanging/freezing for fractions of a second (or up to a second) everytime a sound is being requested from the disk. At least that is my conclusion.

One title where this is very noticeable is Borderlands 2. When I start the game and shoot for the first time (with each weapon) the game shortly freezes clearly waiting for the sound.
Another good example is Portal 2 where a lot of voice files causing hangs sometimes.

One could think that this is a Borderlands issue but I recognize the same on almost every game I can play on OS X:

- All source games (Portal 2, L4D2)
- HL games (Half Life, Counter Strike 1.6)
- Sanctum (1&2)
- Cities Skylines (not as bad in this one)
- Hearthstone
- Borderlands (as mentioned)

What makes me doubt is that I thought that at least most games preload these files into memory or at least open the file pointers. I tested and experienced the same on several Macs (be it SSD or HD, mobile or desktop) including a pretty powerful hackintosh (which is like idling when playing those games on highest settings).

I generally experienced that loading times on OS X are slower than on Windows (dual boot) though the game overall performance is as good as on one or another. I find that weird since my generell impression is that IO is more efficient on OS X.

Can someone confirm this or any ideas what might be the underlying problem here? Is HFS+ just really that slow?

---

**Edit:**

Non-apple kernel extensions:

- com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower
- net.telestream.driver.TelestreamAudio
- org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv
- org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB
- org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt
- org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp

Comment: Do you have any particular audio hardware attached to your Macs? If you run `kextstat | grep -v "com.apple."` are there any non-Apple kernel extensions on your Macs?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan I have a USB soundcard attached to one of my Macs and I also have a few audio related extensions (see edit). I will try to deactivate some and detach the soundcard and see if something changes. Would be sad if it were one of the first two extensions :/

Comment: Soundflower would be my prime suspect - hasn't behaved well since Mountain Lion